# On Windows, how can I prevent an administrator from changing system time?

Tags: windows-7, windows

It's in the title. Is it possible?

I realize that it is probably not possible to totally prevent an administrator from anything so making it very hard (vs. simply double clicking on time in task bar) would be OK too.

It's on Windows 7.

Comment: Are you trying to stop someone winding the clock back to circumvent a time limited trial?

Comment: Is this in an AD environment?

Comment: @MaQleod, no it's not, ordinary single environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of being an administrator is that you can do anything. However, you might be able to run a service that syncs the time from a reliable source every few minutes. There is nothing to keep your admin from stopping the service, of course. Just obscurity. And maybe have your service log instances of the time being out of sync before it fixes it. Of course, the admin could delete the log. But you're trying to understand what's happening on your system, right?

Comment: Windows already has built-in time synchronization. Pretty sure Windows 7 is configured by default to sync with time.windows.com.

Comment: @joel a built in behaviour is not exactly obscure. Also, time syncing is off on my machine and I didn't turn it off, so it might not be on by default (not that that's relevant here.)